# Use Game Manager API in a Remote Display app?

Tags: android, google-cast

Is it possible to use the Game Manager API (for synchronizing player data) in a Remote Display app? If there is, it doesn't seem like it is mentioned in the docs. The Game Manager API examples show that you need to use some JavaScript on the receiver end to make it work, but if you make a Remote Display app, you don't get the option to do that.

Answer (score 2):

When using the remote display, as you noted, everything is happening on your phone/tablet so you should use libraries that are available on the android side to manage your game, being Play Services libraries for games or third party libraries.